# what does jenkinshash in hadoop guarantee?

Tags: hash, hadoop, hashcode

I know that jenkinshash produces an integer (2^32) for a given value. The documentation at this link:
http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/JenkinsHash.html

says
Returns:
    a 32-bit value. Every bit of the key affects every bit of the return value. Two keys differing by one or two bits will have totally different hash values.

jenkinshash can return at most 2^32 different results for given values. 
What if I have more than 2^32 values?
Will it return same result for two different values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As most hash functions, yes, it may return duplicate hash values for different input data. The guarantee, according to the documentation you linked to, is that values that differs with one or two bits are different. As soon as they differ with 3 bits or more you have no uniqueness-guarantee.

The input data to the hash function may be of a larger size (have more unique input values) than the output of the hash. This trivially makes it so that duplicates must exist in the output data. Consider a hashing function that outputs an integer in the range `1-10` but takes an input in the range `1-100`: it is obvious that multiple values must hash to the same value because you cannot enumerate the values `1-100` using only ten different integers. This is called the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Any good hashing function will, however, try to distribute the output values evenly. In the `1-10` example you can *expect* a good hashing function to give a `2` approximately the same amount of times as a `6`.

Hashing functions that guarantee uniqueness are called [perfect hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). They all provide an output data of at least the same cardinality as the input data. A perfect hashing function for the input integers `1-100` must at least have 100 different output values.

Note that [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) the Jenkins hash functions are *not* cryptographic. This means that you should avoid them for password security and the like, but you can use the hash for somewhat even work distribution and checksums.